# limit text with to container width and keep a centered style

Tags: html, css

I want to create an about page like this [example](https://www.thenativeweb.io/#who-we-are)

I think I almost got it, I have a responsive container with 4 people

```css
#about {
  background: #ffffff;
}

#aboutHeader {
  text-align: center;
}

#members {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#aboutAttracting {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.memberContainer {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.memberFocus {
  width: 70%;
}

.sectionHeader {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.section {
  padding: 100px 200px;
}

@media(max-width: 1200px) {
  .section {
    padding: 80px 150px;
  }
  .memberFocus {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 1100px) {
  .memberFocus {
    width: 90%;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 1000px) {
  #members {
    display: block;
  }
  .memberContainer {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .memberFocus {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  .section {
    padding: 60px 80px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
  .section {
    padding: 40px 40px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 400px) {
  .section {
    padding: 20px 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="about" class="section">
  <h1 id="aboutHeader" class="sectionHeader">
    Who we are
  </h1>
  <div id="members">
    <div class="memberContainer">
      <div class="memberImgContainer">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/476389353799680000/484618008455806977/node.png">
      </div>
      <div class="memberTxtContainer">
        <h2>
          Foo Bar
        </h2>
        <p class="memberFocus">
          Webdesign, Desktop Applications, Web Applications, Game Development, Back-End Development
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="memberContainer">
      <div class="memberImgContainer">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/476389353799680000/484618008455806977/node.png">
      </div>
      <div class="memberTxtContainer">
        <h2>
          Bar Foo
        </h2>
        <p class="memberFocus">
          Webdesign, Desktop Applications, Web Applications, Game Development, Back-End Development
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="memberContainer">
      <div class="memberImgContainer">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/476389353799680000/484618008455806977/node.png">
      </div>
      <div class="memberTxtContainer">
        <h2>
          John Doe
        </h2>
        <p class="memberFocus">
          Corporate Design, Print Design, Android Development
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="memberContainer">
      <div class="memberImgContainer">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/476389353799680000/484618008455806977/node.png">
      </div>
      <div class="memberTxtContainer">
        <h2>
          Olaf Svenson
        </h2>
        <p class="memberFocus">
          Webdesign, Desktop Applications, Web Applications, Game Development
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p id="aboutAttracting">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
</div>
```

**Please open the snippet on a big screen, otherwise you will only see the mobile view.**

As you can see, I want to limit the text width to 80% of the container width. The result looks like

[image: current]

The containers itself centred but when limiting the text the view looks wrong.

Normally it should look like

[image]

**but I don't want to use `text-align: center` because the text should still be left aligned.**

How can I fix the text limitation?

[image: future]

Comment: _“but I don't want to use text-align: center because the text should still be left aligned”_ - you can specify text-align for more than one element … Specify it on the parent to align your inner elements, and specify it on your inner elements to align the text in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you

I have used `flex:` to the `.memberContainer` children and removed `.memberFocus` style

```css
#about {
  background: #ffffff;
}

#aboutHeader {
  text-align: center;
}

#members {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#aboutAttracting {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.memberContainer {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.sectionHeader {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.section {
  padding: 100px 200px;
}

.memberImgContainer {
  flex: .4;
  text-align: right;
}

.memberTxtContainer {
  flex: .5;
}

@media(max-width: 1200px) {
  .section {
    padding: 80px 150px;
  }
  .memberFocus {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 1100px) {
  .memberFocus {
    width: 90%;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 1000px) {
  #members {
    display: block;
  }
  .memberContainer {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .memberImgContainer {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .memberTxtContainer {
    flex: 1;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  .section {
    padding: 60px 80px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
  .section {
    padding: 40px 40px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 400px) {
  .section {
    padding: 20px 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="about" class="section">
  <h1 id="aboutHeader" class="sectionHeader">
    Who we are
  </h1>
  <div id="members">
    <div class="memberContainer">
      <div class="memberImgContainer">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/476389353799680000/484618008455806977/node.png">
      </div>
      <div class="memberTxtContainer">
        <h2>
          Foo Bar
        </h2>
        <p class="memberFocus">
          Webdesign, Desktop Applications, Web Applications, Game Development, Back-End Development
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="memberContainer">
      <div class="memberImgContainer">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/476389353799680000/484618008455806977/node.png">
      </div>
      <div class="memberTxtContainer">
        <h2>
          Bar Foo
        </h2>
        <p class="memberFocus">
          Webdesign, Desktop Applications, Web Applications, Game Development, Back-End Development
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="memberContainer">
      <div class="memberImgContainer">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/476389353799680000/484618008455806977/node.png">
      </div>
      <div class="memberTxtContainer">
        <h2>
          John Doe
        </h2>
        <p class="memberFocus">
          Corporate Design, Print Design, Android Development
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="memberContainer">
      <div class="memberImgContainer">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/476389353799680000/484618008455806977/node.png">
      </div>
      <div class="memberTxtContainer">
        <h2>
          Olaf Svenson
        </h2>
        <p class="memberFocus">
          Webdesign, Desktop Applications, Web Applications, Game Development
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p id="aboutAttracting">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
</div>
```

Hope this was helpfull.

Comment: I just tested it on both screen sizes and I think this works fine for all screens :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at your example where i highlighted the boxes with background. You can see that it's already centered, but the 70% width you have added to the paragraph made this preview issue!

https://codepen.io/moradxd/pen/BOQZWx

Although you said that you need to apply 80% width of content, if you tried to increase this width, this preview issue will be arranged better.

I suggest to you these changes where i have set a fixed width for `#about` and centering it within the page by setting `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`. Then adding `padding-right: 30px` for `.memberContainer`, and adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to make this padding to be part of the `50%` width.

Here is the updated demo: https://codepen.io/moradxd/pen/eLBRJa

Check this to understand [box-sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) property

```css
#about {
  background: #ffffff;
}

#aboutHeader {
  text-align: center;
}

#members {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#aboutAttracting {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.memberContainer {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: #eee;
}

.memberContainer:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: #d6d5d5;
}

.memberFocus {
  width: 70%;
}

.sectionHeader {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.section {
  padding: 100px 200px;
}

@media(max-width: 1200px) {
  .section {
    padding: 80px 150px;
  }
  .memberFocus {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 1100px) {
  .memberFocus {
    width: 90%;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 1000px) {
  #members {
    display: block;
  }
  .memberContainer {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .memberFocus {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  .section {
    padding: 60px 80px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
  .section {
    padding: 40px 40px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 400px) {
  .section {
    padding: 20px 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="about" class="section">
  <h1 id="aboutHeader" class="sectionHeader">
    Who we are
  </h1>
  <div id="members">
    <div class="memberContainer">
      <div class="memberImgContainer">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/476389353799680000/484618008455806977/node.png">
      </div>
      <div class="memberTxtContainer">
        <h2>
          Foo Bar
        </h2>
        <p class="memberFocus">
          Webdesign, Desktop Applications, Web Applications, Game Development, Back-End Development
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="memberContainer">
      <div class="memberImgContainer">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/476389353799680000/484618008455806977/node.png">
      </div>
      <div class="memberTxtContainer">
        <h2>
          Bar Foo
        </h2>
        <p class="memberFocus">
          Webdesign, Desktop Applications, Web Applications, Game Development, Back-End Development
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="memberContainer">
      <div class="memberImgContainer">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/476389353799680000/484618008455806977/node.png">
      </div>
      <div class="memberTxtContainer">
        <h2>
          John Doe
        </h2>
        <p class="memberFocus">
          Corporate Design, Print Design, Android Development
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="memberContainer">
      <div class="memberImgContainer">
        <img class="img" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/476389353799680000/484618008455806977/node.png">
      </div>
      <div class="memberTxtContainer">
        <h2>
          Olaf Svenson
        </h2>
        <p class="memberFocus">
          Webdesign, Desktop Applications, Web Applications, Game Development
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p id="aboutAttracting">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
</div>
```